# Tailwindcss : focus:bg-color does not work however hover:bg-color works

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to apply a style to my links when they are focused. But it does not work. I am using tailwindcss (on a React js application).

Here is my code :

```
    <Link to='/clients' className=''>
    
        <div  className="text-2sm font-semibold flex items-center mb-4 hover:bg-[#BE97C6] focus:bg-[#BE97C6] px-2 py-1 rounded-full transition ease-in-out ">

            <IoPersonCircleSharp className="text-xl mx-1"/>
            <p className="">Clients</p>

        </div>

    </Link>
```

Can you, please, help me to solve it ? Thanks you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Link` is getting focused and not the `div`.

Try to set `group` class on `Link` and then `group-focus:bg-[#BE97C6]` on the `div`.